# Hamburger menu not opening after click

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I made my menu to shrink into hamburguer style on
`max-width: 500px;`
I added javascript to close it after clicking a link and it works fine, but after the first link has been click, to open it again, tha hamburguer icon doesn't work but you have to click where the menu links are supposed to be (even without displaying).

```js
var nav = 1;

function navMenu() {
  if (nav === 1) {
    document.getElementById("showmenu").style.opacity = 0;
    nav = 0;
  } else if (nav === 0) {
    document.getElementById("showmenu").style.opacity = 1;
    nav = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(12px + .2vw);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #828282;
  margin: 0 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

label {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .nav {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  .menu a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D736A6;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div class="menu" id="showmenu" onclick="navMenu()">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#aboutme">About</a>
    <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    <a href="#work">Work</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tangential to your question (more of a style point) but rather than recording state with `nav` consider using `menu.classList.toggle('show')` to toggle the class `.show` on and off for your `.menu`.

Comment: What's your media query condition?

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 500px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="menu" id="showmenu" onclick="clickAnyAreaOnMenu();">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#aboutme">About</a>
          <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
          <a href="#work">Work</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function clickAnyAreaOnMenu() {
            let toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
            toggle.checked = false;
        }
    </script>
```